# I can't get UIWebViewDelegate to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to implement a UIWebViewDelegate in my application and I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I would really appreciate a second set of eyes on this.

I know the name MapViewController is confusing, but the WebView is controlling a map (not UIMapView).

Here's the bulk of the code:

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIWebView.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView.delegate = self;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSLog(@"Done loading.");
}
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"hi");
    return NO;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    webView.delegate = nil;
    [webView release]
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: the web view loads the web page just fine. What I'm wanting is to use webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType to pass arguments from JavaScript to Objective-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the initial page you're loading actually display? Are you sure you connected your webview in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yea, everything loads just fine. My HTML file has a handful of links and I want to use objective-C to handle what happens when the links are clicked.

Comment: You could try to set the delegate in IB instead of in code. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: Does your delegate class implement UIWebViewDelegate, btw?

Comment: Isn't that what @interface MapViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> does in the header file?

Comment: Yep. Sorry. Missed that in your initial code. My bad. This should be working. What happens when you pass in something like @"http://www.google.com" for your URL? Does your delegate get called then?

Comment: Nope. It loads google.com just fine but nothing ever appears in the log.

Comment: Just noticed that you're returning NO in -shouldStartLoadWithRequest:. When you do that, -webViewDidFinishLoad will never get called. Does your log message "hi" ever display? Meanwhile, try this example project: http://www.cimgf.com/files/WebViewThing.zip

Comment: May I suggest you to take 5-10 minutes to do up a fresh UIWebView in a new project? There may well be something you missed/messed in IB if you're relatively new to this.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your example and thanks William for the suggestion. I ended up just redoing the project and it worked this time. Not even 100% sure what I did differently!

Answer (score 2):

go interface builder , connect the delegate to the file's owner , then it should work.

1. Open Interface Builder
2. Right click on the Web View object
3. Drag the delegate onto files owner.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. if map.html is in the bundle. Put it on the root of the bundle, not on resources.
2. if it is, right click on it, and choose get info. Verify on TARGETS if the target is checked for the file.

Comment: Thank you, but I should have clarified:
The web view loads the web page just fine. What I'm wanting is to use webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType to pass arguments from JavaScript to Objective-C.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"hi");
    return YES; // for all supported oreintation.
}
```